# Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place to have hobby code critiqued?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Occasionally, I have a piece of code that works but I am not comfortable with it. Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place to have people critique my code?

I know the idea is that it is a place for "questions that can be answered," but mine would be a fairly answerable question, with little leeway for personal judgment. Is it appropriate for me to post that on SO?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/should-so-allow-give-me-some-feedback-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course!

Just like [homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10078/plz-send-teh-codez-for-homework-kthxbai/10098#10098), as long as you're clear about what you want in your question, SO should be a a great place to get that kind of help. Just be careful to not post too much code as that is generally a sign that you didn't narrow your concerns down enough. In general, people don't have the time to wade through hundreds of lines of code, but snippets and high-level designs are OK!

Comment: +1 Detailing the question and asking for specific critique is definitely worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

[As Welbog notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/is-stackoverflow-an-appropriate-place-to-have-hobby-code-critiqued/10736#10736), I have mentioned before: this is fine.  Just keep it short and sweet and, most importantly, demonstrate that you've given the code some thought.

Comment: We can't both link to answers you've given. You're going to have to revoke that link or link to something that links to your answer instead.

Comment: @Welbog: Of course we can!  I'm not above repwhoring.

Answer (score 3):

If the code is working and you just want it to be reviewed for possible improvement, perhaps a better place for posting it would be [the Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). But personally I'm perfectly fine with finding such posts in Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a problem, as long as you tag the question appropriately. If it's really subjective, it should be tagged as such and also made community wiki.

You'll notice it fast enough  (by down or upvotes or comments) if it is accepted or not by the community.